# Create Custom Whitespace in Clojure

Tags: clojure

In Clojure, commas [are treated as whitespace](http://clojure.org/reader). This serves a simple purpose: it helps the human read the code.

I'd like to specify that another character should be treated as whitespace. Is this possible?

If you're curious, it's ∈/∊. If I could type `(for [i ∊ set1, j ∊ set2] (* i j))`, I think that'd be pretty sweet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, the `∊` character is already used for Clojure by several common emacs modes. As such, establishing your own, differing use for it could be quite confusing to readers using such an editor.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. I'm a vi user myself (I know, I know, it's from before my Lisp days).

Comment: FWIW, I think you are much better off writing a custom parser (with something like Instaparse) rather than creating a non-standard hack to Clojure's syntax.

Comment: Well, if I wanted it badly enough, I might do that. But honestly, I don't think I'd go to the trouble for a single whitespace mapping. :-) I can use def/defmacro for all my other cosmetic tweaks (e.g., `¬` for `not`). P.S. Thanks for the Instaparse reference. That looks fun.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not easily possible. See http://clojure.org/reader , in particular:

> The read table is currently not accessible to user programs.